# Throwing error when a particular field is missing or blank when using object mapper in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, objectmapper

I am trying to add validation to my DTO if a particular field is missing or the field is blank then an error should be thrown that a particular field is missing  or is not present
I am using object mapper to map the fields
eg

```
  StudentDto  studentDto = mapper.convertValue(jsonObject, StudentDto.class);
```

DTO class

```
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class StudentDto {
    @NotNull(message = "FirstName is null")
    @NotBlank(message = "FirstName is missing")
    String firstName;
    @NotNull(message = "LastName is null")
    @NotBlank(message = "LastName is missing")
    String lastName;
}
```

I will receive all the values from jsonObject and then I will map those values to DTO. An error should be thrown when a particular field is missing or is blank.But currently I don't receive error the program executes successfully what can I do the achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jackson 2.6 you can use required, Although you must define a constructor annotated with `@JsonCreator` and use `@JsonProperty(required = true)` for each field to force Jackson to throw an exception on your JSON's missing and null fields.

From [docs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html#required()):

> Note that as of 2.6, this property is only used for Creator Properties, to ensure existence of property value in JSON: for other properties (ones injected using a setter or mutable field), no validation is performed. Support for those cases may be added in future. State of this property is exposed via introspection, and its value is typically used by Schema generators, such as one for JSON Schema.

```java
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class StudentDto {

    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    @JsonCreator
    public StudentDto(@JsonProperty(value = "firstName", required = true) String firstName,//
                      @JsonProperty(value = "lastName", required = true) String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response mate this work wonderfully can we also add custom messages and a validation if a particular field is received from jsonobject is missing eg-("lastName","").If the data is like this it should throw error

Comment: Unfortunately, this feature is not implemented in JsonProperty. You need this functionality; I suggest you implement a custom deserializer for your whole DTO or just for some fields and throw your desired exception in it. You can read more about it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization). If you have trouble implementing it, please let me know, so I'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

in request, you have to validate the input before mapping it manually,

in the controller  must add @valid before your Request Body

`````
   @PostMapping(value = "/addStudent ", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     
    public Response addStudent(@Valid @RequestBody StudentDto  refundReq ) {
               
      // your code here ...
    }

    ````
`````

// and also my advice to create a Controller advisor to handle the Errors

```
    @Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    // List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ObjectError error : ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors()) {
          details.add(error.getDefaultMessage());
        logger.error(error.getDefaultMessage());
    }
              // your code to handel response ....
    return new ResponseEntity<>(resp, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```