# SpringBoot: How to differentiate between default and explicitly set null?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have the follow 2 files

```
@Data
public class UserDto {
    private String name;
}
```

```
@PatchMapping(path="/users")
    public String updateUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto){
        log.info(userDto.toString());
        return "hello word";
    }
```

I tried the following 2 request bodies

```
{

}
```

```
{
  "name":null
}
```

Both of them results in

```
UserDto(name=null)
```

How can I distinguish between the explicit set null and the default null?

Comment: You can use Jackson's JsonCreator to throw an exception if the field is missing I believe. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72759979/16034206. If its not missing but an explicitly set null, you can probably make your own null check for that

Comment: @Mar-Z that won't work, because for the validation the value will still be `null` for both request bodies, and for both request bodies the same error message will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see how Spring Boot maps your JSON request body to the Java object.

**Case 1** - the property `name` is missing:

Spring Boot will use the constructor of the Java object **and do not call** the `setName()` method. The Java field has the default value `null`.

**Case 2** - the property `name` is provided but has value of `null`:

Spring Boot will use the constructor of the Java object **and call** the `setName()` method with value `null`.

Knowing this you can implement validation separate for both cases. For example like this:

```
    @NotNull(message = "Name is mandatory (case 1)")
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name must not be null (case 2)");
        }
        this.name = name;
    }
```

You will get different exceptions and can handle them separately.

```
{
}
org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed...
Name is mandatory (case 1)
```

```
{
    "name": null
}
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error:
Name must not be null (case 2)
```